# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted

Tags: laravel

Can someone explain to me a little bit more detailed how can I fix this?

I am trying to get lighthouse pack for graphql-playground.

I have tried this but does not work said can't find this composer.phar

```
 php composer.phar COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 require nuwave/lighthouse
```

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work... should I here

https://prnt.sc/uo8r7r

just instead of 512M put -1 and save that change and then try install pack?

Comment: Try to use `2G` it will be 2GB and restart the apache server.